# `craco start` not compiling, `craco build` does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact, craco

## Context

I've recently switched my CRA dictionary application to Preact using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco). I've made this work using webpack aliases, which replace references to react packages with preact packages (e.g. `preact/compat`).

## What happens when I run...

### `craco build`

I get no errors and the build successfully completes, and you can see the folder here:

[image: folder structure showing build folder]

Everything fine here.

### `craco start`

It starts the predeployment checks (I think), and hits a snag very quickly. It can't find the react module.

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.17
$ craco start
craco:  *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***
E:\_Programming\js\Personal\dictionary-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:
- E:\_Programming\js\Personal\dictionary-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
- E:\_Programming\js\Personal\dictionary-app\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\cra.js
- E:\_Programming\js\Personal\dictionary-app\node_modules\@craco\craco\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\_Programming\js\Personal\dictionary-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:52:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at start (E:\_Programming\js\Personal\dictionary-app\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\cra.js:202:5) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'E:\\_Programming\\js\\Personal\\dictionary-app\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js',
    'E:\\_Programming\\js\\Personal\\dictionary-app\\node_modules\\@craco\\craco\\lib\\cra.js',
    'E:\\_Programming\\js\\Personal\\dictionary-app\\node_modules\\@craco\\craco\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Now of course, that shouldn't happen. I've

1. defined in my `tsconfig.json` `"skipLibCheck": true`, which should stop the checking for libraries, and
2. added webpack aliases to my `craco.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        alias: {
            react: 'preact/compat',
            'react-dom/test-utils': 'preact/test-utils',
            'react-dom': 'preact/compat',
            'react/jsx-runtime': 'preact/jsx-runtime',
        },
    },
};
```

I have no idea why these aliases are working for the build command but not the start command. Any help would be appreciated.

## Code and deployment

[Github repo](https://github.com/TheAyoKhan/dictionary-app/commit/c70daf38d2b25d9f99ce973eafa0c7dd0c6632e0)

[Vercel deployment](https://vercel.com/theayokhan/dictionary-app/7rcX3ePCpuwTUjSv6PF3c4kj6Rba)

Comment: You forgot to add single quotes around react in your craco.config.js. Please add and try again.

Comment: @Raja the error still persists, which is what I expected, even without the quotes, `build` works, so `start` should do the same. It's caused by some other reason entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep `react` installed, unfortunately. It's required by `react-scripts` for starting the dev server and is unavoidable without forking the package.

If you're concerned about the alias working with React still being installed, you can comment out your config and compare build sizes. You should see a sizable difference, confirming your alias works as intended.